# When the new order mail is trigger in WooCommerce? Trying to add a new value before send it

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I have a plugin for official payment (Transbank of Chile) in WooCommerce but this plugin print the `transaction_id` directly in a "thankyou" page. I did to get this transaction and add to the database.

The problem is when WooCommerce send the "new Order" mail the `transaction_id` is never shown. I think that mail already sent before I get the `transaction_id` number. I want to know, when WooCommerce send the new order mail?

Comment: You use use the action 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table' to insert custom order meta data like your transaction_id number.  Just depends where in the email you want the transaction id to be displayed.  This visual guide will help you decide where to put it https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`woocommerce_email_after_order_table`](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_email_after_order_table/) hook to add custom data into Email.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param instance $order
 * @param bool $sent_to_admin TRUE for admin
 */
function wh_addTransactionIdOrderEmail($order, $sent_to_admin)
{
    $order_id = method_exists($order, 'get_id') ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
    $transaction_id = get_post_meta($order_id, "_transaction_id ", true); //<-- replace it with your metakey
    if(empty($transaction_id)) //if blank i.e for Failed/Cancelled order then do not add transaction ID
        return;
    echo '<p></p><p><strong>Transaction ID:</strong> ' . $transaction_id . '</p>';
}

add_action('woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'wh_addTransactionIdOrderEmail', 10, 2);
```

*Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I'm correct this code insert manually the `transaction_id` in the mail form. Right? 
But the problem are that the mail send before I get in the DB the transaction_id. I want to get first the id and then send the mail.

Comment: @ArmandoGarcía: which hook you are using to insert `transaction_id`? because in you plugin if you are setting payment as complete `$order->payment_complete($transaction_id);` then only new order email is trigger unless you have CoD active and customer use it.

Comment: Were is $order->payment_complete?

Comment: Question, Can I add that function directly in plugin's code instead functions.php?

The reason are that `_transaction_id` I get directly via hooks, I asuming that email are sent after showing the `thank_you` page. Right?

Comment: @ArmandoGarcía: yes you can, initialized `woocommerce_email_after_order_table` inside `__construct()` and in the callback write your function name and inside that function just copy paste the code inside `wh_addTransactionIdOrderEmail()` to it.

Comment: WORKS, but I get the `transaction_id` from Zapier plugin but I can't show them in the email yet. Can I update_post_meta() from this code?? I guess that can be resolved in these way.